# Angular how to center mat-icon inside a div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two mat-icons inside a div. These icons are visible based on a value. There are three cases: none is shown, one is shown, both are shown. My problem is that when is just one, I want it to be in the center of the div, but when there are both icons present I want them to have some space between them. I tried to give that div justify-content: space-evenly, but it's not working when just an icon is present (the icon is not in the center of the div). How can I do it?

```css
.icons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

#warningIcon {
  color: #ffa000;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#errorIcon {
  color: #c62828;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="icons">
  <mat-icon id="warningIcon" [style.visibility]="checkWarningAlerts(element.alerts) ? 'visible' : 'hidden'">warning</mat-icon>
  <mat-icon id="errorIcon" [style.visibility]="checkErrorAlerts(element.status) ? 'visible' : 'hidden'">error</mat-icon>
</div>
```

Comment: If you share the reproducible example from any link, then I can help you much better

Comment: I will create a stackBlitz now

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-h8xdrl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts . Is it working? Mainly that is the code. Idk why is not taking the MatIconModule. And basically the function can return false (in that exemple I putter to return true always). What I want is that when bot icons are present -> to be some space between them. When just a Icon is present, I want that icon to be in the center of the div.

Comment: I am unable to install `@angular/material/icon` in the dependencies

Comment: why not use `justify-content:center` and `.icons mat-icon+mat-icon{margin-left:1rem}`?

Comment: U can use something different than icon. Idk, buttons. Probably is still the same issue. Because the problem is about aligning them

Comment: I am unable to install `@angular/material/icon` in the dependencies even after signing through github. Please share the stackblitz link with all dependencies installed.

Answer (score 0):

It's because each item is accompanied by texts that are different in length resulting in unbalanced spacing. You can target the two icons and give them a `flex: 1;` or `flex-grow: 1;` to make them take up the same space making them even. Check the snippet below for your reference:

```css
.icons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.icon {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

#warningIcon {
  color: #ffa000;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#errorIcon {
  color: #c62828;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="icons">
  <mat-icon id="warningIcon" class="icon" [style.visibility]="checkWarningAlerts(element.alerts) ? 'visible' : 'hidden'">warning</mat-icon>
  <mat-icon id="errorIcon" class="icon" [style.visibility]="checkErrorAlerts(element.status) ? 'visible' : 'hidden'">error</mat-icon>
</div>
```

More on `flex` [here](https://css-tricks.com/understanding-flex-grow-flex-shrink-and-flex-basis/).

Comment: No it's not working. When I have just an icon it doesn't center. It's still in the place like when are two icons. When it's just an icon present I want that icon to be in the center of the div